# python library which can be used for vSphere WS SDK

Tags: python, vmware, suds, vsphere, vmware-sdk

I am looking for a python library which can be used for accessing vSphere WS SDK. I have came across two which are having non GPL license:
psphere - https://github.com/jkinred/psphere
pysphere - https://code.google.com/p/pysphere/

Has anybody used these in production. I do not want these for test automation but for a product which could go on a scale of upto 25K VMs.

I saw this post [Python - VMWare vSphere (WEB SDK) - SUDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889762/python-vmware-vsphere-web-sdk-suds). But there he seems to be using it for test automation only. Also I am not only looking for VM operations but also other objects like Host, Cluster, PortGroup, vDS etc.

Regards,
Litty

Answer (score 4):

VMware has published an initial release of their vSphere SDK for Python two weeks ago: [pyVmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know psphere or pysphere but I've used Suds to access the vSphere Web Services. Worked pretty well.

The vSphere WS API is SOAP based and,to the best of my knowledge, exposes everything that's possible via vCenter. It's a bit tricky sometimes, but you can do it.

I don't know what you try to achieve but you should be able to do it with Suds. Of course, you'd have to familiarize yourself with the API: [vSphere Web Services SDK](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/)

At the moment, we're playing around a bit with [vCenter Orchestrator](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-orchestrator/). It's a nice tool (since 5.0). Maybe that's an option for you, too.